# Vue library with vuetify dependencies

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-component, vuetify.js

I need to make a reusable packageable vue component and upload it to npm for my own use in different projects. Am also using vuetify for the styles. And am building it with vue-cli-service.

When I test the component with `npm run serve` (using the vue cli) works but once i transpile it and use it in other libraries, doesn't works correctly.

What I need is to know if there is any way of creating vue libraries with vuetify dependencies.

#### Code sandbox of project:

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-glade-j9icu?file=/package.json

#### Code sandbox to test the transpiled libraries

https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-pond-cs6l9?file=/src/plugins/vuetify.js

#### Repository:

https://github.com/Tauromachian/v-number-stepper.git

Any information would be helpful, I used vue-cli-service as it appears to be the easiest choice but am willing to change to rollup or webpack.

Comment: So what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @AlexMA When i build it and import it in other projects it does'nt work right. It's imported but is'nt rendered right.

Comment: Maybe try building an example in codesandbox? Not sure how else anyone will be able to help with that much info unless they build an app from scratch, figure out how your library works, import it, and then try to debug it.

Comment: @AlexMA you are right, i just was expecting this to be something well defined in the community the kind of things professionals do daily

Comment: It might be, but " is'nt rendered right." is just not enough info. Is there an error? Is all the CSS missing? Is only some of the css missing? There are so many things it could be.

Comment: @AlexMA Am going to create a sandbox, i would like it a lot if you check it later, if posible

Comment: Did you read this articles? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/#vue-cli-install - VUE CLI presets https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/plugins-and-presets.html#presets

Answer (score 3):

I have written a publicly available NPM package that extends Vuetify ([see `v-stripe-elements` on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-stripe-elements)). I also wrote [a detailed series of blog posts on how to do it yourself](https://morphatic.com/2019/09/04/building-packageable-components-to-extend-vuetify-with-typescript-part-1/) including how to set up your dev environment, wrestle with TypeScript, and publish. Also available:

- [demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/morphatic/pen/JjPOwoE)
- [source on GitHub](https://github.com/morphatic/v-stripe-elements)
- **[Blank project template on GitHub](https://github.com/morphatic/vuetify-extension-template)**

Hopefully this will kickstart your development process! I think the project template alone should save you quite a bit of time and effort.

Comment: Hey @morphatic on your stripe component, looking over the source, where do you specify the template of how you want it laid out, the reason I ask is on your card number, you implemented the month/year as part of the component, which means you arent just extending a single text-field, I haven't invested much into ts yet, but im curious where your template is to define the structure of your component?

Comment: @tmarois the v-stripe-card component wraps Stripe's customizable card element (there should be links to the Stripe elements API in the docs), so all of the fields that get baked into the component are generated by Stripe at display time. I mostly just provided CSS to make sure that the style of the fields was compatible with Vuetify and could be modified using props on your vue components.

Answer (score 2):

Your `package.json` file is specifying the same file for both the `main` and `module` tags.  I suspect the problem here is that you're using `import` on a common.js (CJS) module. It works in a single project because you're importing the .vue file from `components` rather than the exported module, so you're testing something very different in the single case.

The `module` entry is optional but exists to allow you to specify a common.js module (i.e.  `require() compatible`) for the `main` entry point, and an ESM module (i.e. `import`) for the `module` entry.

You've provided the same file for both, and a common (cjs) module isn't going to be importable via the `module` entry.

You don't have an ESM variant in your `dist` folder, but you do have a UMD file, which supports both. So it should be compatible with import, which means you could specify it for the `module:` field in the `package.json` file.

**Try changing:**

```
  "main": "dist/v-number-stepper.common.js",
  "module": "dist/v-number-stepper.common.js",
```

**to:**

```
  "main": "dist/v-number-stepper.common.js",
  "module": "dist/v-number-stepper.umd.js",
```

To produce an actual ESM module for imports, see [this page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html#How-do-I-make-multiple-versions-of-my-component) which is really the Vue bible on the standard process for this. It's a different process though, with rollup.

You'll need to publish and pick it up again (unless you're first testing all this with `npm link` in the lib, and `npm link v-number-stepper` in the main project as I suggested in my other answer).

See [this page](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_dual_commonjs_es_module_packages) for info on the package.json fields for CJS and ESM, and [this page](https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/) for info on CJS and UMD.  Also [this page](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html) for info on `npm link`, which will save time if you do something like this a lot.

Comment: Also, you can just copy your v-number-stepper folder to use as a test mainline project, but if you do, you'll want to delete the .vue file for the component from under components, delete the wrapper.js file, and change the App.vue import of the component to use the one from your external module, i.e.:

import NumberStepper from "v-number-stepper";

Comment: And actually I just tried this ran into build errors in the main program, module-related. You might need an actual ESM module there to use import. I don't know how to do that with vue-cli-service, if that's even possible. I know others have had success using rollup to produce an ESM library since it supports that directly with its "--format es" option. See https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html#How-do-I-make-multiple-versions-of-my-component for more.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy all of the code of your `package.json` in another Vue project you could use `npm install`, the CLI will automatically download all of your dependencies.

Comment: This is not true. Vue CLI does not automatically download dependencies with that command. Dependencies additional to the default ones must be explicitly installed with `npm install`.

Comment: @tony19 I dont know where was my head when I wrote that! Oops! I was wrong to write. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem having an external package that has a Vuetify dependency, as long as when you put the pieces together you don't load more than one Vue instance.  Doing so leads to the problem in [this Vuetify Issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4068#issuecomment-586829171) (links directly to the key answer comment, but see also the question at the top, which I asked about).

The primary way to avoid multiple instances if Vue being loaded is to use:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

with *no path in the import* package, no specific filename (like the Common JS or ESM versions, and to avoid conflicts between the Vue runtime that has the compiler vs the one without).

Then if you import it just as `'vue'` then you can define what file you get in your webpack config (as in that Issue above) or similarly if you are using something like rollup.

It looks like that is how you're loading it in both main.js files in your codepens.

Also, you didn't really ask about this but you do not need to publish your dependency library on NPM, if you have both git repos local. You can just use `npm link` in the library project and then `npm link (name)` in the main project, and that will effectively add the library as if you had just added it from NPM normally.  See the [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html) command documentation for the details.

Comment: The problem i have is that when i load the js file that is the result of the transpilation it doesn't works.

Comment: That doesn't sound like anything to do with the question of using a library package external to your project.  But it's difficult to tell with "it doesn't works" without at least an error or visual symptom.

Comment: I suggest you try copying the mainline code to a new project, then copy the library package code directly into it (e.g. copy all components, etc) and try to use it directly to see if the problems are related to it being a library, or something else.  Be sure to check the console for errors, rather than it just not working. Set breakpoints in the browser debugger and find out where it's going wrong.

Comment: I have done that and the library works, if i copy the .vue files into other projects